# Java substring difficulty

Tags: java

I know how to use `substring()` but why isn't this working, the user inputs an equation like 
"5t + 1" with a space before and after the "+". I want `tVariable` to hold the integer before it, in this `case 5` and constant should hold the constant integer in this `case 1`, but I get an out of range error.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class project3030  {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String L1x, tVariable, constant;
        L1x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("This is the format (x=5t + 1)");

        int endIndex = L1x.indexOf("t");

        tVariable = L1x.substring(0, endIndex);

        int beginIndex = L1x.lastIndexOf(" ");
        int endIndex2 = L1x.indexOf("");            

        constant = L1x.substring(beginIndex, endIndex2);

        System.out.println(tVariable + constant);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change it to something more like

```
constant = L1x.substring(L1x.lastIndexOf(" ")).trim();
```

Then when you add the numbers, you have to Parse them before you add them.

```
int constantInt = Integer.parseInt(constant);
```

Or you could use this solution:

```
String[] input = L1x.split(" "); 

// remove the 't'
String tNum = input[0].substring(0, input[0].length() - 1);
int t = Integer.parseInt(tNum); 
int constant = Integer.parseInt(input[2]); 
String operator = input[1];

if (operator == "-")
    constant *= -1;
```

Comment: I tried doing the parseInt and I declared a new variable = constantInt + 5 and printed that out but I got an error " For input string: " 5" I tried doing parseInt instead of constant as the argument but an actual string like "55" and that worked fine.

Comment: I parseInt tVariable and it works, so its only the constant that is having the problem

Comment: it looks like you have a space in your input string: " 5". You could try using the string's trim() method to remove the spaces. String trimmedInput = inputString.trim();

Comment: or int parsedInput = Integer.parseInt(constantString.trim());

Comment: @user3426759 i added the trim() method to the answer. I think having the space there was causing your error.

Comment: it works with positive numbers but it doesn't work when i enter negative numbers, is there a way for me to do this? I just need to be able to store the positive or negative integers in constant and tVariable. I have to solve a system of equations thats why. Thanks

Comment: @user3426759 Do you mean for cases such as: 5t - 1, -5t + 1, and -5t - 1 ?

Comment: @user3426759 I updated my answer. See if that meets your needs

Comment: yeah, it just doesn't read the extra minus symbol in there to store it as a negative number.

Comment: It works, the only adjustment I had to make is instead of "if (operator == "-")" you do .equals it will compare it correctly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because your `substring()` range is off.

You are passing into `substring()` an invalid range because the first index is `beginIndex` which you set equal to `lastIndexOf(" ")` while `endIndex2` you set equal to `indexOf("")` which will occur at the beginning of the string.

Thus, you have your ranges mixed up. When you make this statement:

```
constant = L1x.substring(beginIndex, endIndex2);
```

You're giving it an invaid range
 and will cause the specified error.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it different way. Let's say you create a JFrame and there you could put a textfield for every value, so for every "t" or constants, and then it would be much more simple to get those values. For characters like t or = you could use JLabels, so it would be a mixture of JTextFields and JLabels and I think it wouldn't be that ugly. I used this solution few times.